# Adjust real time series to look like forecast

Tags: statistics, time-series, prediction, forecasting, normal-distribution

I want to write a function that gets a `List` of `double` values and a value for the variance as parameters and returns an adjusted `List`.

```
List<double> adjustTimeSeriesAsForecast(List<double> ts, double variance) {...}
```

This adjusted `List` should differ slightly or strongly from the original `List`, depending on the variance passed. However, the differences should be both above and below the original `List`, so that the mean percentage error (MPE) between the Lists remains the same and only the mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) changes. The returned `List` should look like a forecast.

With this function I want to test a system for stability, which gets a forecasted time series list for weather as input parameter.

How can I adjust a `List` of real weather data to look like a forecast?